# intro.js inputに二つ以上設定するとエラーになる

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

ruby on railsでintro.jsを使用ししたいと思っています。複数ページで利用してます。
が、inputフィールドに２つintroを設定したところ２つめのところでエラーが出ます。

```
    = f.text_field :hoge_sales, class: 'form-control', 'data-step':3, 'data-intro': '売上入力してちょ'

    = f.text_field :poge_cost, class: 'form-control', 'data-step':4, 'data-intro': '入力してちょ'
```

コンソールに出ているエラーは↓こんな感じです。解決法ご存知でしたら教えてください。

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null
at introjs.self-8070938….js?body=1:18
(anonymous) @ introjs.self-8070938….js?body=1:18
```

jsの中身を見るとエラーが出てる箇所はココのようです。d.querySelectorのとこ

```
            b._lastShowElementTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            null != f && (f.innerHTML = a.step);
            h.innerHTML = a.intro;
            s.style.display = "block";
            H.call(b, a.element, s, p, f);
            d.querySelector(".introjs-bullets li > a.active").className = "";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

複数ページを遷移すると発生する問題らしいです。workroundとしてclassNameに値を入れてあげると動くようになりました。

```
  if RegExp('multipage=2', 'gi').test(window.location.search)
      introJs().setOption('showStepNumbers', false).start()
      $('.introjs-bullets li a')[0].className = 'active'
```

もっといい解決方法があれば教えてください